# How to create a ticketing system from email sent by users?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin

I am new to Sharepoint development and was going through tutorials to create a ticketing system which we need badly. I found a lot of information on those but couldn't find if there is a way to create tickets using emails from users to a specified email address. At present we receive emails and create tickets based on those, but it would be really helpful if the emails can directly create the tickets. Remedy has this option but I don't know about Sharepoint. Is there any way to do this or maybe through outlook with an extension that Microsoft provides? Any inputs would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it no code solution:

1. Create a SharePoint Document Library
2. Activate Incoming Email services in that list
3. Create a Form in Microsoft word using quick parts where you can map the columns of the SharePoint Site.
4. Upload that template in SharePoint Library as a default template.

Once you have That set up, publish that form to users as a input form. So if users send that form to abc@xyz.com( which is mapped to that document library)
All the information will be prepopulated and new item would be created.

From that point on you can manage the data you have captured way you want.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can check [`SPEmailEventReceiver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spemaileventreceiver.aspx) class. It's registered like other receivers (but only on document libraries) and can be used to handle `EmailReceived` event.

Incoming email address can be configured in *Library settings > Incoming e-mail settings*.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is site mailboxes. It allows a site to have an email address that everyone can view and read.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/JJ552524.aspx

Another option is to have an incoming email enabled library that everyone has access to. This allows users to email to the library itself and the members of the team can edit and view the "ticket" and mark a column to closed whenever it has been completed.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc262947.aspx